# Сравнить два двумерных массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, сравнение

Добрый день! Наткнулся недавно на такой способ сравнить два массива

```
a1.length==a2.length && a1.every((v,i)=> v === a2[i])
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно его адаптировать под сравнения двух двумерных массивов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В JavaScript не двумерных массивов. Есть массивы, состоящие из массивов. Ну вот так и адаптируйте

```
function isEqualArray1(a1, a2) {
  return a1.length === a2.length && a1.every((v,i)=> v === a2[i]);
}

function isEqualArray2(a1, a2) {
  return a1.length === a2.length && a1.every((v,i)=> isEqualArray1(v, a2[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Без сравнения длин

```
a1.every((v,i) => a1[i].every((v,j) => v === a2[i][j]))
```